# Using distinct column elements in Java Spark to perform operations on related data

Tags: java, database, apache-spark

I'm a bit of a beginner to Spark and am trying to get my head around the different ways of manipulating data. If I were to have a dataframe consisting of a list of students, with all the different test scores that they have achieved, how would I be able to calculate the average score for each student? e.g.

```
+------+-----+
|userId|score|
+------+-----+
|   1  |  65 |
|   1  |  68 |
|   1  |  76 |
|   1  |  75 |
|   2  |  96 |
|   2  |  63 |
|   2  |  60 |
|   3  |  56 |
|   3  |  58 |
|   3  |  75 |
|   4  |  85 |
+------+-----+
```

as

```
+------+-----+
|userId|score|
+------+-----+
|   1  |  71 |
|   2  |  73 |
|   3  |  63 |
|   4  |  85 |
+------+-----+
```

Would anybody be able to give me some pointers as to how to do this?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`df.registerTempTable("userScoreTable");` 
`DataFrame userAvg = sqlContext.sql(` 
`"select score.id,avg(score.scores) from userScoreTable score group by score.id");` 
`List<int,Long> useravgs =` 
`userAvg.rdd().map(rec ->(rec.getInt(0),rec.getLong(1))).collect();`